# Categorizing a nested list based on the indices and the length of inner lists

Tags: python, list, sorting

I would like to categorize my nested list based on their respective indices and the length of the inner lists.

For example, if the initial list is as following:

```
a= [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[3,4],[2,1],[5,6,7],[1,3,5]]
```

I would like to make two new nested lists, in each of which there is the same number of inner lists as the initial list, while the length of inner lists are the same. Furthermore, the index order of the list should stay the same as the initial list and for each non equal list in length, I would like to have a list with values as its previous list.

So, basically I would like the output to be as following:

```
a1=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[4,5,6],[4,5,6],[5,6,7],[1,3,5]]

a2=[[3,4],[3,4],[3,4],[2,1],[2,1],[2,1]]
```

Is there a logical approach to solve this problem?

Comment: "the index order of the list should stay the same as the initial list and for each non equal list in length, I would like to have a list with values as its previous list" - i really didn't understand what you want to do -))

Comment: @marmeladze, you're right

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but the point is that I do not want to change the order of the nested lists. Their indices should stay as the initial list. And for the second part, if you take a look at the desired output, I guess you can get what I mean

Comment: So do you want that some of the sub-lists are duplicated in order to have the same length in both lists? What would be the logic for duplicating, i.e. when would I duplicate, say, `[3,4]` and when `[2,1]`?

Comment: The duplicates should be as the previous existing list in the original list, but if there is no previous list, then the duplicates should look like the 1st upcoming list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an example that produces a `dict` with the sub-list length as the key and a list of all sub-lists that have said length:

```
a= [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[3,4],[2,1],[5,6,7],[1,3,5]]

lengths = set([len(l) for l in a])
result = { n : [l for l in a if len(l) == n] for n in lengths}

print(result)
```

This gives:

```
{2: [[3, 4], [2, 1]], 3: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [1, 3, 5]]}
```

**EDIT**:

If you want to name the lists, you can do that with

```
a1 = result[2] #[[3, 4], [2, 1]]
a2 = result[3] #[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [1, 3, 5]]
```

**EDIT 2**:

After understanding what the OP is asking for, here a code that produces the desired result:

```
a= [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[3,4],[2,1],[5,6,7],[1,3,5]]

lengths = set([len(l) for l in a])

result = { n : [l for l in a if len(l) == n] for n in lengths}

iter_2 = iter(result[2])
current_2 = result[2][0]
iter_3 = iter(result[3])
current_3 = result[3][0]

a1 = []
a2 = []


for l in a:

    if len(l) == 2:
        current_2 = next(iter_2)
    elif len(l) == 3:
        current_3 = next(iter_3)

    a1.append(current_2)
    a2.append(current_3)

print(a1) #[[3, 4], [3, 4], [3, 4], [2, 1], [2, 1], [2, 1]]
print(a2) #[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [1, 3, 5]]
```

**EDIT 3**:

Another approach without iterators would be:

```
a= [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[3,4],[2,1],[5,6,7],[1,3,5]]

a1=[l if len(l) == 2 else None for l in a]
a2=[l if len(l) == 3 else None for l in a]

for l in a1:
    if l is not None:
        curr1 = l
        break

for l in a2:
    if l is not None:
        curr2 = l
        break

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a1[i] is None:
        a1[i] = curr1
    else:
        curr1 = a1[i]

    if a2[i] is None:
        a2[i] = curr2
    else:
        curr2 = a2[i]

print(a1) #[[3, 4], [3, 4], [3, 4], [2, 1], [2, 1], [2, 1]]
print(a2) #[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [1, 3, 5]]
```

**EDIT 4**:

Apparently I'm getting a bit carried away, but here still a generalised solution that works with any kind of sub-list length:

```
a= [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[3,4],[2,1],[5,6,7],[1,3,5]]

lengths = set([len(l) for l in a])
result = { n : [l if len(l) == n else None for l in a] for n in lengths}
current = {}

for n,res in result.items():
    for l in res:
        if l is not None:
            current[n] = l
            break


for i in range(len(a)):
    for n,res in result.items():
        if res[i] is None:
            res[i] = current[n]
        else:
            current[n] = res[i]

print(result)
```

gives:

```
{
  2: [[3, 4], [3, 4], [3, 4], [2, 1], [2, 1], [2, 1]], 
  3: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [1, 3, 5]]
}
```

Comment: The lists aren't same size though?

Comment: @MoeA yes, I realised already that I misunderstood the question -- I'll modify...

Comment: @ThomasKühn Is there also a way to dynamically do the calculations? For instance, if we don't know the how many inner lists with different length we have? 

I have a huge load of data and I have to categorize them by 12. In each group of data samples, there might be none or up to 10 inner lists with different length and I have to do the calculations dynamically! Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @MahdiAbrishami Yes, this is what my last example does (after EDIT 4). It first scans the input for all occurring sub-list lengths, then produces a `dict` with these lengths, and then generates the lists you requested.